# A word for "someone who started a new work/job/etc. but has a long way to go "?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I need a word for this definition:

"Someone who started a new work/job/etc but has a long way in front to achieve the goal."

Do you know of any word?

Comment: See *beginner*. Good Luck.

Comment: Some call these *newbies*

Comment: related: [Noun for “person with intermediate skill”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43111/noun-for-person-with-intermediate-skill) and [Is there a word for a rookie computer programmer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49932/is-there-a-word-for-a-rookie-computer-programmer) and [Is “Beginner” a measurement of time, or skill?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51064/is-beginner-a-measurement-of-time-or-skill)

Comment: also related: [What are common word sets for describing ranks in a profession?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20025/what-are-common-word-sets-for-describing-ranks-in-a-profession) and [Term for a person with absolutely zero knowledge of a topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263302/term-for-a-person-with-absolutely-zero-knowledge-of-a-topic)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

a **venturer**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/venture) noun and [wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/venturer)

> One who engages in excitingnpursuits; (business) One who
>   undertakes a business venture.

Comment: @Ibf: Thanks but I need the subjective word: someone who undertakes this.

Comment: edited to venturer.

Comment: A venturer is not someone who has "begun" a journey or a new job.

Answer (score 0):

I'd described them as **budding** at what it is they're starting:

> (of a person) beginning and showing signs of promise in a particular
>   career or field: *budding young actors*.